# Strange behavior with input when inside translated div on mobile webkit

Tags: mobile, input, webkit, css-transforms

I have noticed a very strange behavior with text inputs on mobile webkit (mobile safari/android stock browser/chrome)

When an input is inside a div (or any container) that is transformed (has -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0px, 0px); for example), when the input is filled with text, the visible area is no longer adjusted to follow the cursor.

Please see a demo at http://jsbin.com/itodip/2/

This is only reproducible in mobile browsers!

The only workaround I have found when working with translated divs was to remove the transform on transitionEnd, but this is not ideal.

Any suggestions and possible workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this bug before and I did find a workaround.  What I did was set the css "left" property to a high negative number, and then I used the "-webkit-transform" property to move it back to be visible on the screen.  For some reason that fixes it.

```
left: -2000px;
-webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 2000, 0);
```

Here's a link to the stack overflow post I did on it: [Scaling input boxes with -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775858/scaling-input-boxes-with-webkit-transform)